# How can I present a virtual credit card on a screen such that card.io can read it?

Tags: image-processing, card.io

Given that I am producing a web app for banking that provides virtual credit cards, I need to display them on the web, such that apps using card.io (Uber, PayPal etc.) can read these virtual cards and load them.

It seems that card.io only works with physical cards and not electronic cards captured from a screen.

What method can I use to produce an electronic image that can be captured from a screen?

Comment: Do you want your phone to scan another screen with the card on it? Or is the card an image on your phone itself?

Comment: The image will be on a computer screen. 
Apps like Uber etc. will be on the phone and scan the computer screen.

Comment: Normally this should work. Have you tested it?

Comment: I have tested it with an image of my card, and it seems to work, but is not the best. 

When I tried to produce the image of a card in Sketch / PhotoShop. I am unable to scan, have tried multiple fonts including OCR A

Comment: https://www.google.co.za/search?q=credit+card&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis_9310YbVAhVkJsAKHSEfDAcQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=983#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=credit+card

For example, none of these will work.

Comment: Yes, but that's because these are fake cards. I would advise you to test it with a real card. And then you still might run into trouble if card.io just doesn't support your type of card. I, for example have a card with vertically typed words which isn't supported. Card.io could still use some work.

Comment: So it turns out that the font counts, as well as using a real card number.